# Why does running a script via a module manifest's ScriptsToProcess directive undefine $LASTEXITCODE?

Tags: powershell, variables, module

I have the following PowerShell module that uses the `ScriptsToProcess` directive in the module's manifest file:

`test-lstExtCode.psd1`:

```
@{
   RootModule        = 'test-lstExtCod.psm1'
   ModuleVersion     = '0.1'

   FunctionsToExport = @(
     'get-importDate'
   )

   ScriptsToProcess  = @(
      'write-import-date.ps1'
   )
}
```

The text of the module body (`test-lstExtCod.psm1`) reads:

```
set-strictMode -version 3

function get-importDate {
   get-content $psScriptRoot/import-date
}
```

And the text of `write-import-date.ps1` is

```
set-strictMode -version 3

get-date > $psScriptRoot/import-date
```

Importing this module or using `get-importDate` undefines the global variable `$LASTEXITCODE`:

```
PS> $LASTEXITCODE -eq $null
True
PS> get-importDate

Thursday, July 29, 2021 9:55:16 PM


PS> $LASTEXITCODE -eq $null
The variable '$LASTEXITCODE' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $LASTEXITCODE -eq $null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LASTEXITCODE:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

I don't understand what causes `$LASTEXITCODE` to be undefined.

If I comment the `ScriptsToProcess` directive, this behavior goes away and `$LASTEXITCODE` is defined after importing the module.

Comment: `$LastExitCode` requires a native program to run when combined with Strict Mode. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- In your scenario, `$LASTEXITCODE` isn't *undefined* by your module import - it was never defined to begin with.
- However, your module import activated *strict mode* version `3` in the *caller's* scope (due to use of the `ScriptsToProcess` module-manifest entry), so that the second attempt to access `$LASTEXITCODE` caused an error, because strict mode version `1` and above only permits access to *defined* variables (whereas by default (strict mode being *off*) an attempt to access an undefined variable evaluates to `$null` rather than causing an error).

---

Note:

- In a pristine PowerShell session (started with `-NoProfile`), the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) is *not* defined.
- It is only created if and when a call to an *external program* is (first) made in a session, in which case it is set to that call's *process exit code*.

Therefore, **with [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 1` or above in effect, you should only ever attempt to access the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) if you know that at least one call to an external program has been made**.

- `Set-StrictMode` defaults to `-Off`, which means that an attempt to access an *undefined* variable quietly evaluates to `$null`, which is why `$LASTEXITCODE -eq $null`<sup>[1]</sup> - in the absence of having called `Set-StrictMode` - initially evaluated to `$true` for you.
- While a module's code generally runs in its own scope domain (aka session state), scripts run via the `ScriptsToProcess` module-manifest entry run in the *caller's* scope and can therefore affect its state. Therefore, after having imported your module, strict-mode version 3 was in effect in your (non-module) code, and the attempt to access `$LASTEXITCODE` failed, given that no external program had yet been called and `$LASTEXITCODE` therefore wasn't defined yet.

  - A corollary is that you should avoid including commands that alter the caller's state *globally* in `ScriptsToProcess` scripts.

Generally, while a `$LASTEXITCODE` value, once set, normally persists until the next external-program call in the same session, it is advisable to check `$LASTEXITCODE` as soon as possible after a given external-program call, for conceptual clarity.

---

<sup>[1] To reliably test for `$null`, place it on the *LHS* of an `-eq` / `-ne` operation; e.g., `$null -eq $var`. If you place `$null` on the RHS - `$var -eq $null` - and `$var` happens to be a *collection* (such as an array), the return value is the *array of matching elements*, i.e. the array of those *elements* in `$var` whose value is `$null`, which is a different operation - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators).</sup>

Comment: I saw you here in [this discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3061) after reading this question and I thought it was pretty relevant to this question too hehe

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon; the linked GitHub issue is primarily about unwitting, mistaken use of _automatic_ variables as _user-defined_ variables, but it would certainly help if all automatic variables were predefined, even if only with a `$null` values.

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me. It would never have occured to me that `$LASTEXITCODE` could be undefined, and I was only superficially aware of the consequences of `set-strictMode` in the script run by `ScriptsToProcess`, thus my confusion.